# Not able to view the source code for Imported jars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Normally in eclipse when you press ctrl + click on a class file eclipse takes it to the source code .

I have a few jars in my projet that i imported through maven . But when i click on a class to see its source not Eclipse tells me that the source of the class is not available . I have tried and give the exact source to the jar with the attach external jar option in the window that opens but no help .

I have no idea why this is happening .

Answer (score 1):

Download source code of jar files through maven using this:

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

If you want to download for specific jar

```
mvn dependency:sources -DincludeArtifactIds=name_of_jar
```

Or, in your `eclipse` plugin in `pom`, specify it

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Run `mvn:eclipse:eclipse` after above from command line

Comment: Thanks . Will that enable me to see the codes on ctrl+click or i will have to manually select source for every class i want to see? Also the version for this dependency is required ?